# R - testthat: using testthat on Rcpp defined functions

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, testthat

I have some `Rcpp` code which I am trying to test using `testthat`.

I have a function `int bar()` in `foo.cpp`, and a test in `test_foo.cpp`   I have declared `// [[Rcpp::export]]` just prior to `int bar()` in `foo.cpp`.

- If I "just" write a test in test_foo.cpp the compiler complains that the function wasn't declared in this scope.
- However, if I declare `int bar();` in `test_foo.cpp`, the unit test runs fine, but `bar()` is not added to `RcppExports.R` and the library doesn't work.

I assume this is a very obvious error on my part, but having hunted to documentation I can't see what the "correct" solution is.   Does anyone happen to "just" know the answer.

Comment: You need testthat's `test-runner.cpp` in your `src` directory and your test file should be  `test-packagename.cpp` if your package is called `packagename`. You should also have testthat's `test-cpp.R` in `/tests/testthat`

Comment: Thanks. I haven't got test-packagename.cpp, I named it after the function not the package.   everything else is in place.  I have a dummy test in test-example.cpp (this works fine), but I can only test the bar when I declare it in the test file.

Comment: Can't you declare it in a common header file that you #include in both `cpp` files?

Comment: I would take a good look at the corpus of CRAN packages---we are now at 2073 using CRAN of which there may well be 1900 using `testhat`.  Just look at those. While I tend to use `tinytest` which I find simpler but, as always, to each their own. That said, I have the C++ part of tests in a subdirectory of the tests, and then `sourceCpp()` the file. That way the tests know the C++ functions, but they don't need to be known package-wide so no `RcppExports.{R,cpp}`.

Comment: Thanks both.  I'm still going to go away and try to understand this better, but short answer is that I'm now testing internal-to-C++ functions that *don't* have `//[[Rcpp::Export]]`.  I'm used to Catch (well, BDD in Catch2) and want to do some serious refactoring on the C++ .   After thinking about it, I suppose there's no point testing an exported function in C++ because you've just made it an R function and can test it there.  But I feel I ought to understand the magic a little better.